# Plotly: How to hide axis titles in a plotly express figure with facets?

Tags: python, express, plotly, facet, axis-labels

Is there a simple way to hide the repeated axis titles in a faceted chart using plotly express?  I tried setting

```
visible=True
```

In the code below,  but that also hid the y axis tick labels (the values).  Ideally,  I would like to set hiding the repeated axes titles a default for faceted plots in general (or even better,  just defaulting to showing a single x and y axis title for the entire faceted figure.

Here is the test code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import string

# create a dataframe
cols = list(string.ascii_letters)
n = 50

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=n)})

# create data with vastly different ranges
for col in cols:
    start = np.random.choice([1, 10, 100, 1000, 100000])
    s = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01*start, size=n)
    df[col] = start + s.cumsum()

# melt data columns from wide to long
dfm = df.melt("Date")

fig = px.line(
    data_frame=dfm,
    x = 'Date',
    y = 'value',
    facet_col = 'variable',
    facet_col_wrap=6,
    facet_col_spacing=0.05,
    facet_row_spacing=0.035,
    height = 1000,
    width = 1000,
    title = 'Value vs. Date'
)

fig.update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True, visible=True)
fig.update_annotations(font=dict(size=16))
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))
```

[image]

**Final Code (accepted answer).  Note plotly >= 4.9**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import string
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# create a dataframe
cols = list(string.ascii_letters)
n = 50

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=n)})

# create data with vastly different ranges
for col in cols:
    start = np.random.choice([1, 10, 100, 1000, 100000])
    s = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01*start, size=n)
    df[col] = start + s.cumsum()

# melt data columns from wide to long
dfm = df.melt("Date")

fig = px.line(
    data_frame=dfm,
    x = 'Date',
    y = 'value',
    facet_col = 'variable',
    facet_col_wrap=6,
    facet_col_spacing=0.05,
    facet_row_spacing=0.035,
    height = 1000,
    width = 1000,
    title = 'Value vs. Date'
)

fig.update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True, visible=True)
fig.update_annotations(font=dict(size=16))
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))

# hide subplot y-axis titles and x-axis titles
for axis in fig.layout:
    if type(fig.layout[axis]) == go.layout.YAxis:
        fig.layout[axis].title.text = ''
    if type(fig.layout[axis]) == go.layout.XAxis:
        fig.layout[axis].title.text = ''
        
# keep all other annotations and add single y-axis and x-axis title:
fig.update_layout(
    # keep the original annotations and add a list of new annotations:
    annotations = list(fig.layout.annotations) + 
    [go.layout.Annotation(
            x=-0.07,
            y=0.5,
            font=dict(
                size=16, color = 'blue'
            ),
            showarrow=False,
            text="single y-axis title",
            textangle=-90,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper"
        )
    ] +
    [go.layout.Annotation(
            x=0.5,
            y=-0.08,
            font=dict(
                size=16, color = 'blue'
            ),
            showarrow=False,
            text="Dates",
            textangle=-0,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper"
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### This answer has five parts:

1. Hide subplot titles (not 100% sure you wanted to do that though...)
2. Hide y-axis tick values using `fig.layout[axis].tickfont = dict(color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')`
3. Set single axis labels using `go.layout.Annotation(xref="paper", yref="paper")`
4. the plotly figure
5. Complete code snippet at the end

***One very important take-away here is that you can edit any element produced with a `px` function using `plotly.graph_object` references, like `go.layout.XAxis`.***

---

#### 1. Hide subplot titles

If you're otherwise happy with the way you've set up your `fig`, you can just include

```
for anno in fig['layout']['annotations']:
    anno['text']=''
    
fig.show()
```

#### 2. Hide yaxis text

You can set the yaxis tickfont to transparent using the following in a loop

```
fig.layout[axis].tickfont = dict(color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
```

That exact line is included in the snippet below that also removes y-axis title for every subplot.

#### 3. Single axis labels

The removal of axis labels and inclusion of a single label requires a bit more work, but here's a very flexible setup that does exactly what you need and *more* if you'd like to edit your new labels in any way:

```
# hide subplot y-axis titles and x-axis titles
for axis in fig.layout:
    if type(fig.layout[axis]) == go.layout.YAxis:
        fig.layout[axis].title.text = ''
    if type(fig.layout[axis]) == go.layout.XAxis:
        fig.layout[axis].title.text = ''
        
# keep all other annotations and add single y-axis and x-axis title:
fig.update_layout(
    # keep the original annotations and add a list of new annotations:
    annotations = list(fig.layout.annotations) + 
    [go.layout.Annotation(
            x=-0.07,
            y=0.5,
            font=dict(
                size=16, color = 'blue'
            ),
            showarrow=False,
            text="single y-axis title",
            textangle=-90,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper"
        )
    ] +
    [go.layout.Annotation(
            x=0.5,
            y=-0.08,
            font=dict(
                size=16, color = 'blue'
            ),
            showarrow=False,
            text="Dates",
            textangle=-0,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper"
        )
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

#### 4. Plot

[image]

#### 5. Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import string
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# create a dataframe
cols = list(string.ascii_letters)
cols[0]='zzz'
n = 50

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=n)})

# create data with vastly different ranges
for col in cols:
    start = np.random.choice([1, 10, 100, 1000, 100000])
    s = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01*start, size=n)
    df[col] = start + s.cumsum()

# melt data columns from wide to long
dfm = df.melt("Date")

fig = px.line(
    data_frame=dfm,
    x = 'Date',
    y = 'value',
    facet_col = 'variable',
    facet_col_wrap=6,
    #facet_col_spacing=0.05,
    #facet_row_spacing=0.035,
    height = 1000,
    width = 1000,
    title = 'Value vs. Date'
)

fig.update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True, visible=True)
fig.update_annotations(font=dict(size=16))
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a: a.update(text=a.text.split("=")[-1]))

# subplot titles
for anno in fig['layout']['annotations']:
    anno['text']=''

# hide subplot y-axis titles and x-axis titles
for axis in fig.layout:
    if type(fig.layout[axis]) == go.layout.YAxis:
        fig.layout[axis].title.text = ''
    if type(fig.layout[axis]) == go.layout.XAxis:
        fig.layout[axis].title.text = ''
        
# keep all other annotations and add single y-axis and x-axis title:
fig.update_layout(
    # keep the original annotations and add a list of new annotations:
    annotations = list(fig.layout.annotations) + 
    [go.layout.Annotation(
            x=-0.07,
            y=0.5,
            font=dict(
                size=16, color = 'blue'
            ),
            showarrow=False,
            text="single y-axis title",
            textangle=-90,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper"
        )
    ] +
    [go.layout.Annotation(
            x=0.5,
            y=-0.08,
            font=dict(
                size=16, color = 'blue'
            ),
            showarrow=False,
            text="Dates",
            textangle=-0,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper"
        )
    ]
)


fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Maybe my OP was not clear.  I only wanted to eliminate the repeated X and Y axis titles ("Date" and "value"),  leaving all other elements of the chart untouched.   The y axis values are all the same unit of measure (say, dollars,  count,  etc),  but have vastly different ranges,  hence the need to still have the tick labels.   I did run the code and it was different than the posted screenshot,  closer to th e desired output,  but was missing the facet titles (the letters) and the spacing between facets was off (too little vertical,  too much horizontal).

Comment: ok,  with some tweaking,  I was able to get the desired output,  and will mark this as answered (and will add full code).  I am using plotly 4.9,  so that solves the spacing issue (I did not notice you commented out those lines :).   FYI -  I was hoping to do this entirely within plotly express as a more simple option  (more like lattice,  ggplot2 in R language has).  Thanks again for the reply!

Comment: @RandallGoodwin The question wasn`t too clear, but I seem to have misread parts of it too. But no worries, I learnt a bunch solving it all the same. Glad it worked out for you in the end! And thanks for marking my suggestion as the accepted answer.

Comment: :) After re-reading my own OP,  I am not sure I understood my own question that well!  Your response hit all the bases,   so thanks again!

Comment: @RandallGoodwin No problem at all! Happy to help!

Answer (score 8):

As a side note on this, I found an even more direct way to eliminate the axis labels from within the plotly express call using the labels argument and providing it with a dict of labels with values of '' for the ones I wanted to eliminate.

This does not result in a single label at the overall figure level though,  but if the figure title is descriptive enough of "Y vs. X",  then maybe the lack of axis labels can be "excused"?  ( or added in as @vestland demonstrated )

Note,  you can "almost" eliminate the annoying repeated facet titles that have "=value" in every single sublot.  i.e. if you add one more entry to the labels dict:

'variable': ''

then instead of getting "variable=variable level",  you just get the the facet variable level,  preceded by the "=" as in the chart below.

**Full Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import string

# create a dataframe
cols = list(string.ascii_letters)
n = 50

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=n)})

# create data with vastly different ranges
for col in cols:
    start = np.random.choice([1, 10, 100, 1000, 100000])
    s = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01*start, size=n)
    df[col] = start + s.cumsum()

# melt data columns from wide to long
dfm = df.melt("Date")

# make the plot
fig = px.line(
    data_frame=dfm,
    x = 'Date',
    y = 'value',
    facet_col = 'variable',
    facet_col_wrap=6,
    facet_col_spacing=0.05,
    facet_row_spacing=0.035,
    height = 1000,
    width = 1000,
    title = 'Value vs. Date',
    labels = {
        'Date': '',
        'value': '',
        'variable': ''
    }
)

# ensure that each chart has its own y rage and tick labels
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True, visible=True)

fig.show()
```

[image]