# stacked + grouped bar chart

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a bar chart using plotly in python, which is both stacked and grouped.
Toy example (money spent and earned in different years):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        year=[2000,2010,2020],
        var1=[10,20,15],
        var2=[12,8,18],
        var3=[10,17,13],
        var4=[12,11,20],
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(
    data = [
        go.Bar(x=data['year'], y=data['var1'], offsetgroup=0, name='spent on fruit'),
        go.Bar(x=data['year'], y=data['var2'], offsetgroup=0, base=data['var1'], name='spent on toys'),
        go.Bar(x=data['year'], y=data['var3'], offsetgroup=1, name='earned from stocks'),
        go.Bar(x=data['year'], y=data['var4'], offsetgroup=1, base=data['var3'], name='earned from gambling'),
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

The result seems fine at first:
[image]
But watch what happens when I turn off e.g. "spent on fruit":
[image]
The "spent on toys" trace remains floating instead of starting from 0.
Can this be fixed? or maybe the whole `offsetgroup` + `base` approach won't work here. But what else can I do?
Thanks!

**Update:** according to [this Github issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2976), stacked, grouped bar plots are being developed for future plotly versions, so this probably won't be an issue anymore.

Comment: Why do you stack var1 and var2?

Comment: Well, in my real data this makes sense b/c the total of var1 and var2 has a certain meaning (and so do var3 and var4). I've modified the example a bit so it makes some sense too.

Comment: I see. Obviously `base` is not modified when you switch off the trace. My plotly knowledge is not deep enough here, but if plotly supports some kind of callback on switching curves on and off, that might be used to modify `base` on demand.

Comment: Your chart saved me a lot of head banging. Thank you very much good sir!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There doesn't seem to be a way](https://community.plotly.com/t/combination-of-grouped-and-stacked-bar-chart/2154) to create both stacked and grouped bar charts in Plotly, but there is [a workaround](https://medium.com/@moritzkoerber/how-to-plot-a-grouped-stacked-bar-chart-in-plotly-df1685b83460) that might resolve your issue. You will need to create subgroups, then use a stacked bar in Plotly to plot the bars one at a time, plotting `var1` and `var2` with subgroup1, and `var3` and `var4` with subgroup2.

This solution gives you the functionality you want, but changes the formatting and aesthetic of the bar chart. There will be equal spacing between each bar as from Plotly's point of view these are stacked bars (and not grouped bars), and I couldn't figure out a way to eliminate the subgroup1 and subgroup2 text without also getting rid of the years in the x-axis ticks. Any Plotly experts please feel free to chime in and improve my answer!

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        year=[2000,2010,2020],
        var1=[10,20,15],
        var2=[12,8,18],
        var3=[10,17,13],
        var4=[12,11,20],
    )
)
        
fig = go.Figure()

fig.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
    xaxis=dict(title_text="Year"),
    yaxis=dict(title_text="Count"),
    barmode="stack",
)

groups = ['var1','var2','var3','var4']
colors = ["blue","red","green","purple"]
names = ['spent on fruit','spent on toys','earned from stocks','earned from gambling']

i = 0
for r, n, c in zip(groups, names, colors):
    ## put var1 and var2 together on the first subgrouped bar
    if i <= 1:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=[df.year, ['subgroup1']*len(df.year)], y=df[r], name=n, marker_color=c),
        )
    ## put var3 and var4 together on the first subgrouped bar
    else:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=[df.year, ['subgroup2']*len(df.year)], y=df[r], name=n, marker_color=c),
        )
    i+=1

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty clever! That's quite cumbersome as well, maybe this calls for a feature request for the plotly team.

Comment: Also - what can I do if I don't want to display the 'subgroup1'/subfroup2' labels? And how can I rotate the year labels in 45 or 90 degrees?

Comment: I'll see what I can figure out for the `subgroup1` / `subgroup2` labels. I couldn't figure out which (if any) parameter can be modified to remove these subgroup names without removing the years as well. I tried a hack such as passing an empty string `''` or `None` as the name of the subgroup, but these collapse the grouped bars.

Answer (score 12):

[Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) (part of recent `plotly` library version) offers a `facet_col` parameter for its [bar chart](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.bar.html) (and other charts as well), which allows one to set an additional grouping column:

> Values from this column or array_like are used to assign marks to facetted subplots in the horizontal direction.

To make it work I had to reshape the example data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        year=[*[2000, 2010, 2020]*4],
        var=[*[10, 20, 15], *[12, 8, 18], *[10, 17, 13], *[12, 11, 20]],
        names=[
            *["spent on fruit"]*3,
            *["spent on toys"]*3,
            *["earned from stocks"]*3,
            *["earned from gambling"]*3,
        ],
        groups=[*["subgroup1"]*6, *["subgroup2"]*6]
    )
)
```

|  | year | var | names | groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2000 | 10 | spent on fruit | subgroup1 |
| 1 | 2010 | 20 | spent on fruit | subgroup1 |
| 2 | 2020 | 15 | spent on fruit | subgroup1 |
| 3 | 2000 | 12 | spent on toys | subgroup1 |
| 4 | 2010 | 8 | spent on toys | subgroup1 |
| 5 | 2020 | 18 | spent on toys | subgroup1 |
| 6 | 2000 | 10 | earned from stocks | subgroup2 |
| 7 | 2010 | 17 | earned from stocks | subgroup2 |
| 8 | 2020 | 13 | earned from stocks | subgroup2 |
| 9 | 2000 | 12 | earned from gambling | subgroup2 |
| 10 | 2010 | 11 | earned from gambling | subgroup2 |
| 11 | 2020 | 20 | earned from gambling | subgroup2 |

Once it's in this format (I believe this is called the "tall format") you can plot it with one function call:

```py
import plotly_express as px

fig = px.bar(data, x="groups", y="var", facet_col="year", color="names")
fig.show()
```

[image: Plotly express bar chart grouped and stacked]

If you want to hide the subgroup labels you can update the x-axis:

```py
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
```

[image: Plotly express bar chart grouped and stacked without x-axis labels]

Comment: If I want to add only the labels of subgroups without the name of group, do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Does point 1 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63389335/1256347) help?

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved it exactly as the indicated link. But I stuck with how to remove the label above each group, 'year' in your example. Or at least move them down instead of above the figures.

Comment: Sorry to repeat myself, but did you try the suggestion in [point 1 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63389335/1256347)? It's the snippet of code in the section **1. Hide subplot titles**. If you run that code, it removes the label above each group. If that doesn't work for you it's best to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and indicate what you've tried so far and where you get stuck.

Comment: Million thanks, that solved my problem :)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Is it possible to add error bars to the stacked columns, i.e. to 'spend on fruit', 'spend on toys' et cetera?

Comment: Have you checked the docs https://plotly.com/python/error-bars/ ? If you did, it's perhaps best to ask a new question where you show what you've tried so far and what your intended outcome is.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did some time ago (might do it again). Just remember that error bars with stacked data are somewhat cumbersome, e.g. https://community.plotly.com/t/stacked-bar-chart-with-calculated-mean-and-sem/47672/6?u=windrose, so I am not sure about stacked + grouped data.