# Grouped Stacked Bar Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, streamlit

I'm kind of wondering, is it possible to make a grouped stacked bar chart in one single chart using Plotly? I' working on a visualization project where I'm going to display true yield along side Firs pass yield, I will display the yield of every station that's I need to put it on a stacked bar.

A series of code displaying a stacked bar with group bar inside one chart.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python plotly - stacked + grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289591/python-plotly-stacked-grouped-bar-chart)